# Mimicing Car Deck for Bluetooth (Music)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a phone and a couple of tablets (All Android 4.0+). I'd like to test a car bluetooth connection with the tablet mimicing the car's bluetooth receiver (sending Media Actions and displaying song info).  The problem is when I pair my tablet with my phone, they see each other as phones and can't send media events. I can't find an app either that mimics this behaviour. I'd like to be able to test this without spending hundreds of dollars. Is this possible?

Comment: What Bluetooth protocol is being used here? If it is just A2DP, Bluetooth headphones should be far cheaper.

Comment: well i also want to be able to display song information and other metadata.

Comment: Let's try this again, as I used the wrong "p" word in my original comment. What Bluetooth profile is being used here? How do you expect anyone to be able to tell you how to mimic a profile if you will not tell us the profile?

Comment: @CommonsWare AVRCP and A2DP namely. My main concern is displaying song metadata, etc.